# How do I get Windows Explorer to show a preview of my files in 'thumbnail' view?

Tags: winapi, windows-explorer

I'm making a 3D editor and I want Windows Explorer to show previews of the 3D models in the files when it's in thumbnail view mode.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to implement a [preview handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776867(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: If I understand the preview handler docs right, it is for the view panel in Explorer, not for thumbnails.

Comment: They're also used for thumbnails (at least on Vista). But of course, implementing IExtractImage works too (and may be better for pre-Vista OS). The advantage of preview handlers is that they're 'out-of-process' and can't crash the shell, are called in a background thread with low priority, ...

Comment: Isn't that the case for IExtractImage as well on Vista?

Answer (score 4):

You have to write a shell extension that implements IExtractImage2 and extracts the thumbnail for Explorer. Oh, and it's COM, so better expect to feel dirty afterwards.

Comment: I use raw C++ so I expect to feel filthy after a day or two rolling in COM.

Comment: Or you can use EZShellExtensionsMFC and feel clean and tidy :-)

Comment: I don't feel clean and tidy after using something that has the name MFC in it :X